# Отличия между стеком и вектором

Tags: c++

В чем различия между ними? И в каких случаях предпочтительней использовать ту или иную структуру данных?

Comment: О чем вопрос? Об абстрактных структурах данных "стек" и "вектор"? Или о `std::stack` и `std::vector` в С++? Если первое, то что тут делает тег [C++]? Если второе, то вопрос, мягко говоря, бессмыслен: в С++ это сущности разного "порядка" - адаптор и контейнер - и сравнивать их впрямую, это как сравнивать корову и треугольник.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Идеологически разница в том, что в стеке для операций доступна только вершина, а вектор - структура с произвольным доступом, т.е. в любой момент времени можно можно получить доступ к любому элементу.

Что касается реализации, то зачастую стек это просто адаптер некоторого контейнера. В качестве адаптера может выступать тот же вектор.

КО говорит, что стек предпочтительней использовать когда Вам нужен... стек, т.е. структура LIFO (last in, first out). Например, широко известная "польская нотация" реализуется на основе стека.

Answer (score 3):

Как мне кажется, стек широко реализован в программировании и используется при выходе из вложенных циклов и вложенных вызовов функций.

"Антагонист" стека - очередь.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486487/stdvector-vs-stdstack

stack не контейнер, а **адаптер**. Он использует vector, deque (по умолчанию) или другой контейнер с подходящим интерфейсом, который хранит элементы. Запомните: stack определен как:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

Все что делает stack -- **ограничивает интерфейс для используемого контейнера.** Производительность операций полностью определяются свойствами используемого контейнера.

В более общем случае: вы можете использовать в собственной реализации стека "алгоритмы и структуру данных" оптимизированные под тот факт, что вам нужен доступ только к вершине стека, и **недоступно** обращение к произвольному элементу по индексу, или сканирование (поиск или фильтрация), и получить выигрыш по памяти/скорости.